# NSpoint from NSTextView insertion point

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I have an NSTextView and require the coordinates of the insertion point to display a view there upon user interaction.

There is a function to get the character index from an NSPoint.  I am wondering if there is any easy way to do the opposite?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure: `[textView firstRectForCharacterRange:[textView selectedRange]];`

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well in a nice simple line of code!

Comment: This was deprecated in 10.6, one should now use `- (NSRect)firstRectForCharacterRange:(NSRange)aRange actualRange:(NSRangePointer)actualRange`

Comment: And nowadays: `- (NSUInteger)characterIndexForInsertionAtPoint:(NSPoint)point;`

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do it with an NSTextView subclass, overriding
`-drawInsertionPointInRect:color:turnedOn:` to cache the drawing rect and using the center of the rect (or some other interior point).

NB: I haven't tried this.

Comment: Thank you for offering a solution.  I ended up going with [textView firstRectForCharacterRange:[textView selectedRange]];